# Sharing Intent Not working Properly

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, sharing

I have one quote application. I have implemented share and copy function in it. I am facing issue is that I am not getting shared first time sharing quote. Means if there 50 quote in list and if I try to share any quote from list than it is not sharing anything. after that if I move on another quote and try to sharing than its working fine. I have same issue in copy function also. I also face some time issue like if I share quote number 50 than its sharing another number quote. Please help me for solve the bug. Thanks
My Activity for it is like below.

```html
 

public class QuoteDialogActivity extends Activity {

 DAO db;

 static final String KEY_ID = "_quid";
 static final String KEY_TEXT = "qu_text";
 static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "au_name";
 static final String KEY_PICTURE = "au_picture";
 static final String KEY_PICTURE_SDCARD = "au_picture_sdcard";
 static final String KEY_FAVORITE = "qu_favorite";
 static final String KEY_WEB_ID = "au_web_id";

 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> quotesList;
 HashMap<String, String> map;
 ImageButton btnnext,btnprev,star,copy;
  int pos,lstcount = 0;
  ScrollView ll_quote;
  String quote_id;

 TextView text;


 String quText, quAuthor, quPicture, quFavorite,quoteShare;
 int auPictureSDCard;

 String isFavorite;
 
 String auPictureDir;
 String siteUrl;

 private ImageLoader imgLoader;

 /**
  * Register your here app https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
  * consumer key and secret
  * */
 String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY;
 String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET;

 // Preference Constants
 static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
 static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
 static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
 static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

 // Twitter oauth urls
 static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
 static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
 static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

 static final String PREF_KEY_FACEBOOK_LOGIN = "isFacebookLogedIn";

 Typeface tf;

 // Internet Connection detector
 private ConnectionDetector cd;

 // Alert Dialog Manager
 AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

 String quote;
 ProgressDialog pDialog;
 private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

 private static SharedPreferences facebookPreferences, twitterPreferences;
 Cursor c, c2;

 private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
 private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
 private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;

 //private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

 // ==============================================================================

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  imgLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
  
  //TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
  //TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = getResources().getString(R.string.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
  
 // uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
  //uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

  //facebookPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("facebookPref", 0);
  //twitterPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("twitterPref", 0);

  db = new DAO(this);
  db.open();
  c2 = db.getSettings();
  if (getIntent().getIntExtra("isQOTD", 0) == 1) {
   c = db.getOneQuote(mSharedPreferences.getString("QOTD", ""));
  } else {
   c = db.getOneQuote(getIntent().getStringExtra("QuoteId"));
  }

//  if (c.getCount() != 0) {
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   setContentView(R.layout.quote_dialog);

   // ============================ check if user want to display
   // ============================ background image for quote

   if (c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("background")).equals("1")) {

    Random random = new Random();
    int idNumber = random.nextInt(20 - 1 + 1) + 1;
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
    Drawable d = null;
    try {
     View topShadow = (View) findViewById(R.id.topShadow);
     View bottomShadow = (View) findViewById(R.id.bottomShadow);
     topShadow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     bottomShadow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("backgrounds/" + String.valueOf(idNumber) + ".jpg"),
       null);

     layout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

   // ===========================================================================================

   quText = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT));
   quAuthor = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AUTHOR));
   quPicture = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PICTURE));
   auPictureSDCard = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PICTURE_SDCARD));
   quFavorite = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FAVORITE));

   text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text); // title
  // tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/devnew.ttf");
   //text.setTypeface(tf);

//   author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.author); // author
//   picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture); // thumb

   text.setText(quText);
//   author.setText("- " + quAuthor.trim());

//   if (auPictureSDCard == 0) {
//    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
//    InputStream istr = null;
//    try {
//     istr = assetManager.open("authors_pics/" + quPicture);
//    } catch (IOException e) {
//     Log.e("assets", assetManager.toString());
//     e.printStackTrace();
//    }
//    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
//    picture.setImageBitmap(bmp);
//   } else {
//    siteUrl = getResources().getString(R.string.siteUrl);
//
//    auPictureDir = siteUrl + "global/uploads/authors/";
//    imgLoader.DisplayImage(
//      auPictureDir + quPicture, picture);
//   }

   
   AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
   InputStream istr = null;
   try {
    istr = assetManager.open("authors_pics/" + quPicture);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("assets", assetManager.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
//   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
//   picture.setImageBitmap(bmp);

   final ImageButton dismiss = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.close);
   dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
     finish();
    }
   });

   
   
//=============================Next Button and Prev Button
   star = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.star);
   
   btnnext = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
   btnprev = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.PrevioustButton);
   pos= getIntent().getIntExtra("Pos",0);
   quote_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("QuoteId");
   lstcount = getIntent().getIntExtra("LstCount",0);
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   
   final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> quotesList =(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Quotes");
   btnnext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(pos == lstcount)
             {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "End of List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             else
             {
     int p = pos+1;
    text.setText(quotesList.get(pos).get(KEY_TEXT));
    quFavorite = quotesList.get(pos).get(KEY_FAVORITE);
    quoteShare = quotesList.get(pos).get(KEY_TEXT);
    Log.e("ErrorMsg", "quoteShare is: " + quoteShare);
     quote_id = quotesList.get(pos).get(QuoteDialogActivity.KEY_ID);
    isFavorite = quFavorite;
    if (isFavorite.equals("0")) {
     star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_off);
    } else {
     star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_on);
    }
    pos = p;
    FirstFav();//new
    Log.i("quote is",quote_id);
    }
   }
  });
   
   
   
   btnprev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
      if(pos == 1 ||pos == 0)
               {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start of List",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else
               {
      int p = pos-1;
     text.setText(quotesList.get(p-1).get(KEY_TEXT));
    quFavorite = quotesList.get(p-1).get(KEY_FAVORITE);
    quote_id = quotesList.get(p-1).get(QuoteDialogActivity.KEY_ID);
    isFavorite = quFavorite;
    if (isFavorite.equals("0")) {
     star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_off);
    } else {
     star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_on);
    }
     pos = p;
     FirstFav();
     }
    }
   });
   
   //======================================================= Swipe
   ll_quote = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
   ll_quote.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      int downX, upX;
    
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                downX = (int) event.getX(); 
                Log.i("event.getX()", " downX " + downX);
                return true;
            } 

            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                upX = (int) event.getX(); 
                Log.i("event.getX()", " upX " + downX);
                if (upX - downX > 100) {
                 if(pos == 0 || pos == 1)
                 {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start of List",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  int p = pos-1;
                  quFavorite = quotesList.get(p-1).get(KEY_FAVORITE);
               quote_id = quotesList.get(p-1).get(QuoteDialogActivity.KEY_ID);
               isFavorite = quFavorite;
               if (isFavorite.equals("0")) {
                star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_off);
               } else {
                star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_on);
               }
                  text.setText(quotesList.get(p-1).get(KEY_TEXT));
        pos = p;
        FirstFav();
                 }
                } 
                else if (downX - upX > -100) {
                 if(pos == lstcount)
                 {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "End of List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  int p = pos+1;
                  quFavorite = quotesList.get(pos).get(KEY_FAVORITE);
            quote_id = quotesList.get(pos).get(QuoteDialogActivity.KEY_ID);
           isFavorite = quFavorite;
           if (isFavorite.equals("0")) {
            star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_off);
           } else {
            star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_on);
           }
                  text.setText(quotesList.get(pos).get(KEY_TEXT));
        pos = p;
        FirstFav();
                 }
                }
                return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
   });

   // ========================== share button

   final ImageButton share = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.share);
   share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     
     Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
     sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,pos);
     sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
     startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
   
   });

   //copy button
   
   final ImageButton copyy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.copy);
   

   copyy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     
  ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
  ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text",quoteShare);
  clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Status Copied",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
   
     
    }
   });
   
 
   // ========================== set as favorite and unfavorite
   
   
   isFavorite = quFavorite;
   if (isFavorite.equals("0")) {
    star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_off);
   } else {
    star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_on);
   }

   star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

     if (isFavorite.equals("0")) {
      isFavorite = "1";
      star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_on);
     } else {
      isFavorite = "0";
      star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_off);
     }

     if (getIntent().getIntExtra("isQOTD", 0) == 1) {
      db.addOrRemoveFavorites(mSharedPreferences.getString("QOTD", ""), isFavorite);
     } else {
//      Log.i("quotes",quotesList.get(pos).get(String.valueOf(KEY_WEB_ID))+"POS"+pos+"quid"+quotesList.get(pos).get(KEY_ID));
      db.addOrRemoveFavorites(quote_id, isFavorite);

//      db.addOrRemoveFavorites(getIntent().getStringExtra("QuoteId"), isFavorite);
      if (getIntent().getIntExtra("quotesType", 0) == 2 && isFavorite.equals("0")) {

       Intent i = new Intent(QuoteDialogActivity.this, QuotesActivity.class);
       i.putExtra("quotesType", 2);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
       finish();
       startActivity(i);

      }
     }
    }
   });

//  }

 }

 // ==============================================================================

 public void FirstFav()
 {

  String Image_id=quote_id;
  quFavorite = db.getFavQuotes(quote_id);
  if(quFavorite.length()>0)
   isFavorite = quFavorite;
  else
   isFavorite = "0";
  if (isFavorite.equals("0")) {
   star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_off);
  } else {
   star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_on);
  }
 }

 //===================================================================================
 

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you could be better understood if you cleaned up the code to only the relevant part, or, if you want to keep the "Run code snippet" option, make a second code box above the full one that has a cleaned-up version (for example, no one needs to see all those imports, we assume you got those right if your code runs).

Comment: hi ! I have edited it :)